# Confidence Intervals for a proportion

Tags: probability

My question is this:

I'm trying to get confidence intervals around the means of the proportion of survey respondents that chose a particular ordinal or nominal answer choice.

What is the reason for the requirement that a sample not make up more than 5% of the population?  Is there another statistical test that would be more appropriate for my use?  My two surveys have samples that make up about 6% and 10% of their populations, respectively.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Where did you hear of such a requirement?  Possibly the concern is that when the same makes up more than 5% of the population, the individual draws are no longer approximately independent.  That doesn't mean you can't base a confidence interval on it, but it might mean you'd want to adjust the length of the confidence interval in a way that might be somewhat complicated.  I haven't thought through the details of this.  I'd start by googling "finite population sampling", although at this point I am uncertain about whether that will lead you to the end of the search.

Comment: Michael is correct. You can use the standard method,but you will get a narrower confidence interval if you use the finite correction factor.